# bots-webserver.py ( bots edi open source ) gives a 500 page

Tags: python, django, bots, erp, edi

i've just installed cherrypy, django, and bots along with python. i've ran bots-webserver.py and it results in a 500 error html page.  Is there something that I need to set up to see the bots-monitor user webpage? It just displays the 500.html django template page.  What am I missing?

Comment: Which OS? Which versions of bots and django?

Comment: hey eppye, im using Mac OS X Mavericks

Comment: Which versions of bots and django? Bots 3.1 needs django 1.3 or 1.4. I know bots works on Mac OS X (though I do not have that myself).

Comment: im using cherrypy 3.2.4, django 1.4.13, and bots 3.1.0

Comment: I had originally installed bots, and when i ran bots-webserver.py, it complained about an ini file, so i dragged over the ini file from the bots archive config folder, into the site-packages/bots/config folder, and that error went away. but then now it just shows a 500 error page (using a 500 template page that i made).

Comment: I noticed that there are a few folders from the tarred archive that are not in the site-packages/bots folder.  Were they supposed to copy over?

Comment: yes, all files/folders in the archive should be in  site-packages/bots. Any idea what could be causing this? (it is a standard python install)

Comment: i have no idea, i have several versions of python installed on my computer, including 2.4-2.7 i think. and when i installed cherrypy and django, i installed django 1.6 or the latest version, uninstalled it with pip, then reinstalled 1.4.13 because i had noticed that the versions were wrong. django and cherrypy were installed in /library/python/site-packages/bots i think.  all the installs look ok, because when i check the versions of cherrypy and django in the python command prompt, they print the right versions.

Comment: the version thats used with bots is 2.7

Comment: ok, i copied over the missing files and i can now see the administration and can log in.

Comment: ok, i logged in but, i cannot see the bots-monitor run menu or anything, but i was able to login, when in the admin page, it just shows information about the server and everything.

Comment: if i highlight the links on the right i can see them, otherwise they are invisible, seems the styles are messed, i can login/logout but thats all i can do.